# NIC Bonding Rocky Linux 8

Tags: nic, bonding, rocky-linux

Since teaming is going to be deprecated, Red hat suggested to use bonding instead, however bonding in the past had the limitation of being able to bond two network cards only, which was not the case for teaming (you could add for example add 4 NICs to team and get the max throughput; is this still the case for bonding? I think since it is going to replace teaming, it should not, however I could not find any document or source about it.

Would appreciate some info.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding [Network bond vs network teams](https://forums.rockylinux.org/t/network-bond-vs-network-teams/6209) and

> *I could not find any document or source about it.*

the following links might be able to answer most of the questions.

- [Comparison of Network Teaming to Bonding](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/de-de/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/networking_guide/sec-comparison_of_network_teaming_to_bonding)
- [Network bonding or network teaming: Feature comparison](https://documentation.suse.com/smart/network/html/reference-network-bonding-teaming-comparison/index.html)

> *... bonding in the past had the limitation of being able to bond two network cards only ...*

Not as far as know and from experience in the past, see in example also [Does bonding 3x 1G NIC's into one make a 3G NIC?](https://serverfault.com/questions/840074/)